# populating jquery datatable ajax txt file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I'm a `jquery`/`ajax` newbie and going through data table examples. I'm having problems populating the data table with txt data in eclipse. I just get a loading message. Any assistance would be appreciated.

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Extn</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
     </tr>
  </thead>
</table>

<script>    
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').dataTable( {
    "ajax": "data/object.txt",
    "columns": [
      { "data": "name" },
      { "data": "position" },
      { "data": "office" },
      { "data": "extn" },
      { "data": "start_date" },
      { "data": "salary" }
    ]
  } );
} );
</script>

/////object.txt 
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "Tiger Nixon",
      "position": "System Architect",
      "salary": "$320,800",
      "start_date": "2011/04/25",
      "office": "Edinburgh",
      "extn": "5421"
    },...................
```

Comment: Are you sure about the path?

Comment: If my solution suffices in answering your problem please mark it an an accepted answer so that in future people who run into similar or same issue they know the solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your code sample, you had the line,

`"columns": [{ "data": "name" },{ "data": "position" },{ "data": "office" },{ "data": "extn" },{ "data": "start_date" },{ "data": "salary" }]`

Simply change the columns to "columnDefs" which refers to the column defaults option in the datatable plugin.

And also, you are calling the data-table plugin on an id called "example" which you have not defined. So give your table an `id="example"`

So the final code should look like

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').dataTable({
    "ajax": 'array.txt',
    "columnDefs": [{   /* changed this */
      "data": "name"
    }, {
      "data": "position"
    }, {
      "data": "office"
    }, {
      "data": "extn"
    }, {
      "data": "start_date"
    }, {
      "data": "salary"
    }]
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.5/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.5/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Extn</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Now this above code snippet ***WILL NOT*** work because the path to the array.txt is wrong. Copy the array.txt file locally. Fiddle or code snippet does not allow the ajax requests through them.

Here is the sample array.txt (copied from the data table website @ https://www.datatables.net/examples/ajax/data/arrays.txt )

Hope this helps. **Happy coding :)**

**Screenshot on my local machine**

[image]

Comment: I have an arrays.txt file locally within the project.

Comment: Check the path if it is pointing to the right place. In my example the arrays.txt file was on the same folder as the html file. Now id the path is right, then make sure your .txt file has the same array structure like in the link I provided where I took the arrays.txt from. If the structure dont match or proper brackets are not closed, then it wont work either.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance.  I have arrays.txt in my eclipse project but unable to see the data unlike your screenshot.  How is your ajax path configured?  Does it have to be a Dynamic project?

Comment: If you have it configured as an eclipse project, what is the folder structure you are following?

Comment: ajax path does not matter as long as the proper path is given in relation to the project root. no outside paths allowed

Comment: your arrays.txt file has to be inside the webapp folder. because technically the webapp folder is the project root. If you have it anywhere else, for eg. resources, then it is out of the context path totally

Comment: C:\Users\Admin\workspace\JqueryTables   : Both html and arrays.txt file reside in this directory.  Maybe I need to configure my path?

Comment: your path should be ---  \workspace\{project name}\src\main\webapp\  here should be your html and arrays.txt file, if you have configured your project right in eclipse