# Load Text File Into JQuery DataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am attempting to load a text file into JQuery DataTables.  This is my HTML I have set-up for the button press

```
<div style="text-align:center;padding:20px 0px 0px 0px;">
    <span class="badge badge-info" style="font-size: 1.5rem; font-weight: 700;padding-bottom: 10px;margin-bottom: 20px;" id="txtFile">Get Registered Names</span>
</div>
```

And this is the html I have setup for the actual JQuery Datatable

```
<div>
    <table id="tblData" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>
</div>
```

And this is the JQuery I am wanting to use to load the table from the text file

```
$(function (){
    $('#txtFile').click(function() {
        $('#tblNames').dataTable({
            "ajax": 'registeredusers.txt',
            "columnDefs": 
            [{  
              "data": "Name"
            }]
        });
    });
});
```

This file is located in `/var/www/html/` and I want to display it to the user on a button press event.  How would I do this?

Comment: Does this link help you? And try the text file accessible via browser https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29307354/populating-jquery-datatable-ajax-txt-file.

Comment: @vimuth - Can I set this ``"ajax": "data/object.txt",`` to my local path of ``'"ajax": "/var/www/html/names.txt"``

Comment: No it should be just 'names.txt'. And try '/names.txt' this too if it doesn't work. And it should be visible from browser like this.https://www.datatables.net/examples/ajax/data/arrays.txt. ex:- `"ajax": "names.txt"`

Comment: @vimuth - I get this error ``DataTables warning: table id=tblDomains - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1``

Comment: Can you share the link to .txt file so I can check json format is correct?

Comment: @vimuth - https://gofile.io/d/f9uUfg

Comment: Try adding this inside "names.txt". `{
    "data": [
        [
            "jason",
        ],
        [
            "mark",
        ],
        [
            "richard",
        ],
        [
            "bob"
        ]
    ]
}
`

Comment: @vimuth - Do I need the single quote around the start and finish?

Comment: And notice I have added only a few names only.

Comment: yes you need :)

Comment: @vimuth - I get this error ``http://datatables.net/tn/3``  Did a straight copy/paste of your sample data above

Comment: It seems like you can initialize datatable multiple times. Long story short you can't execute `$('#tblNames').dataTable({` Multiple times but in your code it executes over every button click.

Comment: Check this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47250789/how-to-load-datatables-data-on-button-click. And check they are distroying the datatable and reinitialize over every button click by this `$("#grd").dataTable().fnDestroy()`

Comment: none of the answers were accepted.  Any one in particular I should pick?

Comment: The first one with the code I mentioned. Try adding  `$("#tblNames").dataTable().fnDestroy();` before your `$('#tblNames').dataTable({`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229966/discussion-between-vimuth-and-james-mandatory).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **registeredusers.txt** should have data like this,

```
{
    "data": [
        [
            "jason",
        ],
        [
            "mark",
        ],
        [
            "Richard",
        ],
     ]
}
```

And you can't initialize datatable multiple times. So add `$("#tblData").dataTable().fnDestroy();` before create datatable.

```
$(function (){
    $('#txtFile').click(function() {
        $("#tblData").dataTable().fnDestroy();
        $('#tblData').dataTable({
            "ajax": 'registeredusers.txt',
            "columnDefs": 
            [{  
              "data": "Name"
            }]
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try getting content from php file with

```
$data = file_get_contents('yourfile.txt');
```

then get this data and replace with your rows

Comment: I get an error ``Uncaught ReferenceError: file_get_contents is not defined``  The exact syntax I tried was ``$data = file_get_contents('/var/www/html/names.txt');``

Comment: Kindly, refer to this example
https://tryphp.w3schools.com/showphp.php?filename=demo_func_filesystem_file_get_contents